# OnClick function need to open only child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi this is my HTML code right here:

```
<div class="title-of-theme">
     <img class="plus-minus-sign theme-sign" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt="">  <h3>Theme</h3>
</div>
<div class="title-of-question">
     <img class="plus-minus-sign2" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt=""><h4>Question —›</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis cumque earum incidunt inventore maiores natus sit tempore? Nisi, sequi.</p>
</div>
```

And my JS code:

```
$('.plus-minus-sign, h3').on('click', function () {
   $('.title-of-question').toggleClass('show-menu');
});
$('.plus-minus-sign2, h4').on('click', function () {
   $('.faq p').toggleClass('show-menu');
});
```

Because i will have many h3 titles and paragraphs, and those paragraphs and titles have all the same class i need to do something when i click on one h3 it should open only his child elements
But now when i click on one h3 it open all elements

Comment: here in your markup h3 has no child elements

Comment: can you explain clearly what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Im trying to make this : On the page only h3 is shown, when i click on h3 it should open h4 tag, when i click on h4 it should open p tag, but i have to many of this tags on my page and they are nested so i must use child elements because situation right now is that when i click on one h3 tag it opens all h3 tags on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DOM traversal from the clicked element, which you can get using the `this` keyword within the event handler, to find the required element to toggle the class on. Try this:

```js
$('.plus-minus-sign, h3').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.title-of-theme').next('.title-of-question').toggleClass('show-menu');
});
$('.plus-minus-sign2, h4').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.title-of-question').find('p').toggleClass('show-menu');
});
```

```css
.show-menu { border: 1px solid #c00; } /* for demo only */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-of-theme">
  <img class="plus-minus-sign theme-sign" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt="">
  <h3>Theme</h3>
</div>
<div class="title-of-question">
  <img class="plus-minus-sign2" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt="">
  <h4>Question —›</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis cumque earum incidunt inventore maiores natus sit tempore? Nisi, sequi.</p>
</div>

<div class="title-of-theme">
  <img class="plus-minus-sign theme-sign" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt="">
  <h3>Theme</h3>
</div>
<div class="title-of-question">
  <img class="plus-minus-sign2" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt="">
  <h4>Question —›</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis cumque earum incidunt inventore maiores natus sit tempore? Nisi, sequi.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes its good, i opet section by clicking h3 but it doesnt work on the h4 section, when i click it it doesnt opet paragraph.

Comment: As you can see from the example above it sets the class correctly (as the red border appears around the related `p`). If you can update your question to include the code you amended we may still be able to help

Comment: code <div class="title-of-theme">
      <img class="plus-minus-sign theme-sign" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/plus-sign.png" alt="">
     <h3>Theme</h3>
</div>
 <div class="title-of-question">
      <img class="plus-minus-sign2" src="images/plus-sign.png" alt="">
       <h4>Question —›</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum Nisi, sequi.</p>
</div> 
this is the whole html, i copy pasted your script but i doesnt work when i click on h4 element, it wont opet paragraph